# "return" is not returning to calling function

Tags: java, loops, return

I want to search for an email in inbox with subject line, email is taking sometime to get into mail box. if email is not found in iteration then wait for sometime and again search for email  and when email found return true;

```
public boolean searchForEmail(String MySubject, String linkAddress, String attachment) {
    boolean flag = false;
    List<WebElement> unreademeil = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
    for (int i = 0; i < unreademeil.size(); i++) {
        if ((unreademeil.get(i).isDisplayed()) == true) {
            System.out.println(unreademeil.get(i).getText());
            if (unreademeil.get(i).getText().contains(MySubject)) {
                unreademeil.get(i).click();
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        System.out.println("No mail with Subject ::--:: " + MySubject);
        while (counter < 40 && !flag) {
            sleep(10000);
            counter++;
            cloop();
        }
        SoftAssertor.asserTrue(isElementPresent("//*[contains(@text()='" + MySubject + "')]"),
                "Failed to search a email with Subject line  ::: " + MySubject);
    }
return flag; 
}



public void cloop(){
searchForEmail(SubjectLine, seeDetailsLink, "xpath");
}
```

Above Program is to search an emails with subject line. sometime it is taking time received an email. So the program is continued search after sleep(10000).

Problem arises at return statement, "return flag" statement redirected to "cloop()" under while loop even through the condition of while loop is not satisfied i.e. "flag== true"; 
due to this program goes in infinite loop. Please help

Comment: You should write `flag = cloop();` you need to think about refactoring this code. You have two methods calling each other..this is a great chance to go in infinite loop and memory overflow exception

Comment: Please consider 1) Change cloop() to return a boolean (as Chetan Ranpariya suggested, 2) changing the spelling to `unreadEmails`, 3) ensuring your `counter` is (re)set correctly before you enter the "while" loop, and - 4) Yes:  Please consider refactoring.

Comment: Hi Chetan Thanks for response, Can you please elaborate in details. ?  flag = cloop();  cloop () function is just to calling searchForEmail() function once again. hence cloop function's return type is void.

Comment: Thanks  paulsm4, Cloud you please let me know structure of refactoring ?

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring is a solution :

```
public boolean searchForEmail(String MySubject, String linkAddress, String attachment) {
        boolean flag = false;
        sleep(200);
        List<WebElement> unreademeil = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='bqe']"));
        for (int i = 0; i < unreademeil.size(); i++) {
            if ((unreademeil.get(i).isDisplayed()) == true) {
                System.out.println(unreademeil.get(i).getText());
                if (unreademeil.get(i).getText().contains(MySubject)) {
                    unreademeil.get(i).click();
                    flag=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag=true
    }

    public boolean isSearchPassed(String MySubject, String linkAddress, String attachment){
        boolean flag= false;
        int count =0;
        while (!searchForEmail( MySubject, linkAddress,  attachment) && (count< 45)) {
            sleep(10000);count++;   
        }
        return flag=true;
    }
```